# setting the affinity of an array of threads

Tags: c, linux-kernel, pthreads, affinity

My code doesn't seem to work the way I want, I have tried to find where the problem is but I just can't seem to see that there's something wrong with it ...I think I may have understood the whole thing wrong.
I am trying to set the affinity of a thread,I want to make it run on a specific cpu,then when I run it and display the value of sched_getcpu() it's not the correct value,not the cpu I forced my thread to run on.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sched.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void *fonction(void *arg){
    int n=(int)arg;
    int res=1;
    int i;      
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++) res=res*i;

    fprintf(stderr,"calculating %d! by cpu %d\n",n,sched_getcpu());
    sleep(5);
    return (void*)res;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pthread_t *threads=NULL;
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    void *retour;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int cpu;
    int ar;
    int val;
    int numcpu=sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
    if(sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&ar)!=1){
        fprintf(stderr,"error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   
    threads=calloc(numcpu,sizeof(pthread_t));
    if(threads==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"calloc error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(cpu=0;cpu<numcpu;cpu++){
        val=ar-cpu;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
        CPU_SET(cpu,&cpuset);
        if(pthread_create(&threads[cpu],&attr,fonction,(void*)val)!=0){
            fprintf(stderr,"problem creating thread\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(&attr,sizeof(cpu_set_t),&cpuset)!=0){
            fprintf(stderr,"error setting affinity\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        pthread_join(threads[cpu],&retour);
        fprintf(stderr,"%d!=%d done by %d\n",val,(int)retour,cpu);
    }

    free(threads);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

the execution gives
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S27ko.png)

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of text output.  Include the text directly in the question (treat it like code; if you're feeling fancy, add `<!-- language: lang-none -->` on a line on its own before the output, but no-one should criticize you for not including that).

Comment: Never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to confirm that the desired command line parameter has actually been entered by the user.

Comment: regarding this kind of statement:  `fprintf(stderr,"calloc error\n");`  when a system function fails and returns an error indication, should also output (to stderr)  the associated text  that indicates why the system thinks the error occurred.  The best function to handle all this is `perror()`

Comment: to avoid a memory leak, after the call to `calloc()`, any following call to `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` needs to be preceded by `free( threads );`

Comment: @user3629249: Actually, call to `exit` *automatically* releases some types of resources, and memory heap among them. Some programmers prefer to explicitely call `free()` in any case, but this is not required.

Comment: As for the problem: `pthread_create` creates a thread according to **current** content of **attributes**, that is without affinity. Futher modifications of `attr` by calling `pthread_attr_setaffinity_np` has no effect on already created thread.

Comment: thanks,I have forgotten that pthread_attr_setafinity_np is for setting affinity of  a thread which is not yet created.I have placed this statement before the pthread_create statement and it works well.it was a good hint thanks